# Finding Unique Pairs of Non-Null Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find the most common combinations of non_null columns from a query that's stored in a database. I am using SnowSQL to run the queries.

That data looks like the format below. Only difference is the actual data is there are 20 additional columns not listed.

| ID | Query | Price | Size | Weight | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `price=32&weight=120` | True | False | True | False |
| 1 | `price=32&weight=120&size=m` | True | True | True | False |
| 1 | `price=50&weight=20` | True | False | True | False |
| 1 | `year=1985&weight=120` | False | False | True | True |
| 1 | `price=32&weight=120&size=m&year=1990` | True | True | True | True |

The desired result will be along these lines:

| Combo | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Price, Weight | 2 |
| Price, Weight, Size | 1 |
| Year, Weight | 1 |
| Price, Weight, Size, Year | 1 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier if you normalized the schema, using an attribute-value table instead of separate columns for each attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html):

> **If the key or value is NULL (i.e. SQL NULL), the key-value pair is omitted from the resulting object**

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) AS combo, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM  (SELECT NULLIF(Price, False) AS Price,   -- nullifying False values
              NULLIF(Size, False) AS Size,
              NULLIF(Weight, False) AS Weight,
              NULLIF(Year, False) AS Year
       FROM tab) s
GROUP BY combo
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Output:

[image]

Data prep:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(ID INT, Query TEXT, Price BOOLEAN,
                           Size Boolean, Weight Boolean, Year Boolean)
AS
      SELECT 1, 'price=32&weight=120',  True,   False,  True ,  False
UNION SELECT 1, 'price=32&weight=120&size=m',   True,   True,   True,   False
UNION SELECT 1, 'price=50&weight=20',   True ,  False,  True,   False
UNION SELECT 1, 'year=1985&weight=120', False, False, True,     True
UNION SELECT 1, 'price=32&weight=120&size=m&year=1990', True, True, True, True;
```